# Is it possible to have multiple components source code hosted under one trunk in Git like in SVN?

Tags: git, version-control

Ours is a big product development with around 50 components. We don't want to have separate Git repositories for each component. Also, we don't want a developer to clone the complete repository if we plan for having a single repository folder and all components as directories inside that.

My questions are:

1. is there a way to host all the components as one repository?
2. If so, can the developer clone only his module code each time rather than cloning the complete repository?

Comment: If you don't want a developer to clone the complete repository then I'm not sure what lead you to git. That's fundamentally what defines a distributed version control system. Why don't you want that?

Comment: Good question, cause a all these component seemed to be that they should be versioned together and not separated.

Comment: Since I want to host all the components under a single tree like trunk in svn, I don't want to clone the complete tree. I meant it this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is by design no way to check out only a subdirectory with git. What you could do instead is put the subprojects into [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html). This would allow you to version the complete set of your whole software while still allowing to only checkout part of it.